# Pentaho: userid and password arguments in direct links to plugins

Tags: pentaho

Integrated Pentaho (v5.1.0 in Linux) with Compiere ERP (v.3.81 in Windows )

Try to Pass Userid and Password in URL . **requestParameterProcessingFilter** (api & Plugin ) Updated in the file system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml

**Method 1:**

> testserver:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%home%admin%31.prpt/viewer?userid=admin&password=password

Always Prompting arguments the userid and password with a HTTP login box in all Browser

**Method 2:**

> admin:password@testserver:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%home%admin%31.prpt/viewer

Working Fine in Chrome , Prompting login box at first launch and asking confirmation box (Access from other PC) , Link dosnt work in Internet Explorer

could anyone please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is some security changes between version 4.8 and 5.0 (and 5.1):

### **Method 1:**

According to this [bug-report](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-10708) you shuld change `applicationContext-spring-security.xml` like you did in next way:

```
/api/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
      /plugin/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
```

**Important: Restart BA Server!**

### Method 2:

Internet Explorer doesn't like ftp-like connecting parameters.
[Here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-access-an-ftp-site-in-ie-when-the-url-contains-special-characters) I found how to bypass it, it worked to me, but I lost 20min to properly change the URL.

> **:** as **%3A**
>
> **?** as **%3F**
>
> **** as **%5C**
>
> **%** as **%25**
>
> **#** as **%23**
>
> **/** as **%2F**

Comment: Yes, I followed the same but Prompting login box at first launch and asking confirmation box

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify: /pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
      <value>
        <![CDATA[CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /webservices/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/repos/**/parameter=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS        
        /plugin/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionReuseDetectionFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor]]>
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```